# How to use a SOAP data service as the source for a lookup list?

Tags: 2010, lookup-column, soap

I have created a SOAP data source using SP Designer 2010. Now I am trying to figure out how to use that data source as the source for a lookup field in a list? Is that possible?

Comment: Not in a standard SP Lookup field, you have to write your own

Comment: Dang. Thanks. If you put that as an answer then I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: Can you delete the question?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Huh? Why? Is it not a valid question?

Comment: Valid question but arcane topic.. so its better to delete old content than (like Google) forever serve answers that are outdated, wrong, surpassed. Just think how valuable Google **could** be if it never gave you SP2010 answers again (not you.. you poor soul is still on 2010 :-/

Comment: Isn't it possible another poor soul on 2010 may ask the same question and come to this question with an answer that they can't? Maybe I am missing something here. If I need to delete I will, I just don't get why.